How to dilute a chocolate mousse that is too flavorful?
I have a cup of chocolate mousse that is just too flavorful. Is it possible to dilute it without breaking the emulsion? It has "double cream"-like thickness.

What do you mean by too flavorful? Too intense chocolate taste or more like too heavy/ calorydense?

Both, actually :)

If you want to make your chocolate mousse a little lighter and aerier I would suggest to beat an egg white separately and once it is all stiff carefully mix/ fold it into the mousse.
Otherwise you can simply adjust the portion size. A typical chocolate mousse is a mixture of molten chocolate and heavy cream (plus some beaten egg whites). A cup, generally meaning 250 ml is a lot. Going back to your original ingredients that could come to something like half a bar of chocolate and a similar amount of cream. Such a thick and heavy mousse can be very tasty but say shot glass can already be a good portion size.

If serving smaller portions, which is a good idea, garnishing with fresh fruit (berries perhaps) would both lighten it further and add visual size

This was store bought from a speciality shop. I overall love it but just hope to make it airier and less flavorful. I'll try your advice regarding folding in the egg whites. Do you suggest to bring the mousse to the room temp first?

@Kentzo The room temperature sounds like a good idea. The mousse should be softer and blend easier than right out of the fridge.
